# Do I need 2 sockets for this setup or one will do?

Tags: sockets

I am implementing a small client that connects to a server for online rooms creation.

A client has an API for creating, joining rooms, etc on the server side. All these API invocations against the server wait for a response from the server, that is received in json format.

Now, on the other side, given one of these clients, I want to receive notifications of when another user joined the same room as me, asynchronously.

My guess is that this is not possible to do with a single socket and I will need at least 2 of them:

- one socket for API invocations (since this already uses read/write on the socket) for request and response
- one socket to receive notifications

My questions are:

1. is there a way to do this with a single socket in a reasonable way?
   or
2. it is mandatory to use at least 2 sockets in this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the client allocate just one socket (and connect a single TCP connection) is sufficient, provided you have a well-defined messaging protocol between your client and server.

In particular, I suspect that you perceive a need for a second TCP socket connection primarily because you're unsure about how a single-socket solution would be able to handle multiple different kinds of operations (i.e. RPC calls *and* asynchronous notifications) properly, without one type of operations interfering with the functionality of the other.

In a purely message-passing design, handling everything via a single socket is straightforward -- when your client wants to send a message to the server, it calls your `SendMessage()` function (or whatever you call it), and your code queues up the bytes to be sent across the socket; conversely, when the server sends a message to your client, your I/O code receives the bytes, and if all of the bytes of the message have been received, it parses them and calls your appropriate callback function (`MessageReceived()` or whatever) to react to them appropriately.  Since your client never blocks anywhere (other than perhaps in some `WaitForNextEvent()`-type-call such as `select()` or `poll()`), integrating multiple simultaneous tasks is not a problem.

In general, I recommend against RPC-style semantics (i.e. where your client code calls a function-call that hides a network operation and the function-call doesn't return until a reply has been received back from the server) because it leaves your client at the mercy of the server and the network's connectivity -- in particular it will cause your client thread to freeze up (blocked in an RPC-call) whenever there is a temporary network outage, which is not a very good user experience.

That said, if you *must* use RPC-style semantics, asynchronous-notifications are still possible with just one socket; you just have to include code inside your RPC-functions that gives them the ability to call an appropriate callback-function (i.e. `SomeAsynchronousEventOccured()` or whatever you like to call it) when they receive an asynchronous-event-occurred message from the socket.  Note that that means that the asynchronous-callback function can get called before your RPC-function returns its network-provided result, which might be a bit surprising to some programmers, so be sure to document that it is a possibility.  (At least it still gets called inside the same thread, so race conditions won't be an issue, though re-entrancy problems might be)

Comment: Actually my client is synchronous (I did not want to complicate things much). So I have more or less something like main thread calling SendMessage() and another thread trying to receive the notification in the same socket. But it can happen that it happens during a reply. I want to keep it simple but I am not sure I will be able to do it :)

Comment: Beware of the wallpaper-bubble-effect, where you try to avoid complexity in one place, only to have the complexity pop up elsewhere instead  :)   (in particular, whenever I've tried to go with a synchronous/blocking/multithreaded design, I ended up with responsiveness-problems whenever the network or server didn't respond promptly, and difficulty getting the client program to quit cleanly and reliably--due to the fact that the client was "stuck" in a blocking function somewhere.  In the end I found that a single-threaded/non-blocking design was more reliable, despite its initial complexity)

Comment: Basically I am sending json, receiving json and will get json from async notifications. I receive in the response (data_length, json_data) and in notifications also. maybe should add another field to distinguish both kinds?

Comment: Having a field that clearly and unambiguously describes what the message's purpose is, is always a good idea :)

Comment: Jeremy, I do agree with your assessment, but my strategy at this point is to have a prototype quick and dirty to enable finishing a prototype of a bigger product overall. After that I agree that for a robust solution maybe it is . better an async design directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one connection between the server and each client. That connection can transmit messages in both directions (API calls and notifications).

Most socket APIs work like that: You open a port on the server by creating a listening socket. Each client that connects becomes another socket. That socket represents the connection to that client. Likely, you need to maintain a list of all connected clients. There needs to be a single socket bound to an open port.

Comment: I am not sure I explained the question well. I am talking about the *client*. The server already gets one open connection per client. But the client needs to execute api calls against the server. The server replies to those calls. But, additionally, on the client side, I need to receive asynchronous notifications (for example if another client connected from another place and joined my room)

Comment: @GermánDiago yes, I seem to have misunderstood. But again, you need just one connection. Define a binary protocol to be able to send request/reply pairs. That protocol would be symmetric. The server can call the client and the client can call the server. Better yet, use one of the ready-made protocols and libraries. Writing socket code is extremely hard if you are new to it.

Comment: I am not new actually. Just not an expert at the task :)